# How do I to add a certain character to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have this code:

```
$tags = preg_match_all('~%([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+)%~', $text, $matches);
```

It works great but I would like to be able to add the "_" character and I don't know how.

I will be looking forward to some answer!

Peter

Comment: Well, *where* do you want to add it? And what does not work?

Comment: Give us an example of a string that contains '_' that you would like to apply this to.

Comment: @harke I didn't say anything didn't work. At the momne the only permitted characters are 0-9 a-z. I simply want to add  _. It looks like nickhars answer might work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them to the permitted chars in each group?:

```
$tags = preg_match_all('~%([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)%~', $text, $matches);
                                     ^                ^
```